# Expectation of little o in probablity

Tags: st.statistics, pr.probability, probability-distributions

If I have $Z=o_p(1)$ where $o_p$ is the little-o in probability. I'm interested in find some properties about $E(Z)$.

My first idea was

$E(Z)=E(Z  (1_{Z>\varepsilon} + 1_{Z\leq\varepsilon}) ) \leq E(Z^2)P(Z>\varepsilon) +\varepsilon P(Z\leq\varepsilon)$,

for some $\varepsilon > 0$.

As you can see, it's required that $E(Z^2)<\infty$ and it don't seems like an appropriate condition.

So my philosophical question is: Can we give to  $E(Z)$ any sense?

Regards.

Comment: Incomprehensible homework, voting to close.

Comment: To avoid closure, you need to rewrite it more carefully.  But probably it is not a "research level" question even so, and should be at another site, not here.

Answer (score 1):

It may help to consider the indicators of the intervals [0,n] on the probability space [0,1] with Lebesgue measure.